# Selenium multiple tabs "error: no such window: target window already closed" in python

Tags: python, selenium

So I have the first tab; the main tab. I want to open multiple tabs using selenium and once their task is done, to close them until we're back to the original first tab

```
url = "https://www.google.com/"
i=4
for each in reversed(range(i, 0, -1)):
    print(each)
    driver.execute_script(f"window.open('{url}');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[each])
    #do stuff
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[each-1])
```

I get the following error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed from unknown error: web view not found`

I know its something to do with the index values of each tab, where 0 would be the inital tab, correct me if I'm wrong, but I can't get it to work.# properly.

The best I could do is to get it to close each tab randomly until left with 2, then suddenly it closes both of them (**no tabs left, exits browser**) when reach the value of `1`

Answer (score 0):

your issue starts here "driver.close()" - close method closes the current window - no matter how many tabs you have, but it doesn't kill chrome instance (drive.quit() - does the job). If you want to close the current tab you can use a workaround like

```
# Close current tab for windows/linux
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')

# Close current tab for Mac
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'w')
```